# detect wifi but not can't connect

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, kali-linux

I have installed Kali, it works fine when I use in a home but in office, i can't connect to wifi, not even LAN. I try to update the drivers but still ask me password again and again. I try with the pass of my colleague also but the same thing again and again. Wifi card works fine in a home.
Any solution how I can resolve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Cheapest, easiest and quickest way around this is to buy a USB Wifi Adapter to connect at the office. The alternative is to spend hours looking through message boards in the hope that something just *might* work.